# How do i convert String to IStream And Vice Versa, in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, istream

i want to use :

```
Rslt := WrapCompressedRTFStream(OleStream, 0, Uncompressed);
```

where : OleStream, Uncompressed : IStream;
and RTFStringIn RTFStringOut are String;

1. i have the RTFStringIn (As String).
2. convert it to OleStream (ISTREAM).
3. run WrapCompressedRTFStream.
4. convert the Uncompressed to RTFStringOut.

and then save it as RTF file.
all that without using ExtendedMAPI.

Answer (score 3):

For conversion use TStreamAdapter:

```pascal
...
Stream := TStringStream.Create(your_string_here);
istr := TStreamAdapter.Create(Stream, soReference) as IStream;
...
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, simple. i will check it

Comment: @mazluta When? And when will you accept this answer?